# Using matchTemplate to find the a mount of transformation, rotation and scale between two images using opencv

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to extract the amount of transformation, rotation and scale between a template image and a source image. I want to use template matching but I don't know how to extract transformation, rotation and scale amounts. Could someone help me ?

Comment: that sounds like a bad idea. template matching expects exact copies, any rotation or scaling will only degrade it. instead go for feature matching ( SURF, SIFT, etc ) and find the homography from that

Comment: I'm concerned with exact copies.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you posed can be addressed in many ways but it doesn't look like template matching is the right solution.

1. One way of solving it could be to use [SIFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) to compute the keypoints in each image and after that you could find the consensus of features between the two pictures. Once you have the matches, you can calculate the [homography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography_%28computer_vision%29) mapping between the two pairs of point sets. One example is shown below with a card. Notice that you need to handle wrong matches, but there are algorithms for that. You can find an example of SIFT with OpenCV [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_sift_intro/py_sift_intro.html).

[image]

2. A more complex way of handling that would be to perform a point-set registration. There is a very good algorithm called [CPD](https://sites.google.com/site/myronenko/research/cpd) which given two point-sets, it calculates the correspondence between points and estimate the transformation in a dual step optimization (Expectation Maximization). CPD can assume different types of transformations, such as rigid, affine, and non-rigid. CPD was written in Matlab with C via mex.

[image]

Comment: Hi, please don't forget to accept the answer if this is what you needed.

Comment: I know this is quite long ago. How to get the points from the picture for CPD? I.e. how to get the "red points" from the image on the right? The CPD algorithm requires an array of points as an input. I don't think CPD takes in an image as an input right??